# How to predict twitter tweet reach using python?

Tags: python, twitter, social-networking, data-science, network-analysis

How to predict twitter tweet reach on a specific area ? For e.g if a user tweets in china then how can i predict about its reach there is a website named [keyhole.co](http://keyhole.co) they tells the total reach of tweets containing the hashtag that user searched for. Below is the screenshot that is the result when i searched for hashTag (#Retweet)
[image]
Basically, they are tells reach of a hashtag.
But the question is that how to predict the about tweet reach in a specific area (country or region).

**Backgroud Research:**

I know that i can check count of how many times the Tweet has been viewed through twitter [Engagement API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/metrics/get-tweet-engagement/overview.html#EngagementTypes). I have aslo checked that there is a api called [TwitterCounter](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterCounter) that contains the Scripts for counting tweets. Uses 'search/tweets' or 'statuses/filter' Twitter resource to get old or new tweets, respectively.

There are also ways to get counts of retweets like discussed in this [answer](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-get-a-count-of-the-replies-and-retweets-for-a-particular-tweet). Moreover, there are other ways to get views/reach of old tweets and track specific word or hashtag in tweets etc.

**But my question is that how can i predict about a tweet reach ?**

I have been searching for this for past several days but didn't able to find a way or solution to do it.

Can anyone please help me by telling the way to get what i want or tell me any solution by which i can do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A bit offtopic, but why does changing a hashtag in your tweet change its reach? Are people somehow following certain hashtags on Twitter? Wasn't aware of such a feature.

Comment: @Bemmu: yes, peoples are following certain hashtags on Twitter and according to my research hashtag and the words that you use in your tweet changes it reach. Hashtags are Twitter’s way of bundling information together by keyword. People following hashtags are interested in that content. If your content suits one, you’ll reach an audience that’s keen to engage with it.

Comment: OK, but if I go to the page https://twitter.com/hashtag/test for example, there is no follow button.

Comment: Well following a hashtag here means that peoples search for certain hashtags and including some certain hashtags in your tweet changes it reach. Hope you understand what i am saying! :)

Comment: OK, so basically you would need to know how many times a certain hashtag is searched for. OR have some historical data of tweets that had some certain hashtags and see what their reach was.

Comment: Maybe that keyhole data is just some guess based on some dataset they have?

Comment: No i want to predict about the whole tweet reach. and keyhole is not making gusses they track/searched for a hashtag form all the tweets that contain the hashtag which you searched for and ofcourse the tweets they search from are of specific time you can check there wesbsite to know how they are giving results there is also a timeline given in which they searched for a hashtag in tweets

Comment: Sounds like you would either need a huge number of samples from the engagement API to create some kind of machine learning model, or have some access to Twitter internal metrics. It doesn't sound like a weekend Python project in any case.